# Is there any difference to use getters of sythesize properties or direct access to object?

Tags: objective-c, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iVar property, access via self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088801/ivar-property-access-via-self)

I understand that it's to use setters for instance variables, but are ther any reasons to use getters istead of direct access?

```
.
.
NSArray *instArray;
.
.
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSArray *instArray;
.
.
@synthesize instArray;
.
.
//are the following lines equal?
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.instArray];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:instArray];
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914399/does-it-make-a-difference-in-performance-if-i-use-self-foobar-instead-of-foobar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271657/when-to-access-properties-with-self http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494157/in-objective-c-on-ios-what-is-the-style-difference-between-self-foo-and-foo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318499/ivars-with-and-without-self

Comment: Thank you for above links they are all useful for me.

Comment: Glad that you found them helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For purely synthesized getters, there is no difference, unless you want atomic access (atomic properties surround the code with a lock).

For properties that have getters with extra code, there is a difference. Sometimes, it makes sense to avoid the extra code, so you use the ivar (say, `xyz`) directly. Otherwise,if you want the extra code to be invoked, you use the property, using `self.xyz`.